# Why does the langchain agent custom template {agent_scratchpa} contain objects? How does it parse into a string?

Tags: python, langchain, agent

Template：
prompt_template = """
...
...

history:
{chat_history}

new input: {input}
{agent_scratchpad}
"""

But if I print out prompt, why is the stuff in {agent_scratchpad} object? Instead of a string?
history:
[]

new input: Shenzhen weather
[**AIMessage**(content='getWeather\n`json\n{\n  "action": "getWeather",\n  "action_input": "shenzhen"\n}\n`'), **HumanMessage**(content="TOOL RESPONSE: \n---------------------\nShenzhen Weather Friday March 29, 2024 February 20, 24 ° C Cloudy 22 ~ 28 ° C Humidity: 89% Wind Direction: Southwest wind Level 2 Ultraviolet: None Air quality: Excellent PM: 20 Sun: 06:18 Sunset: 18:38\n\nUSER'S INPUT\n--------------------\n\nOkay, so what is the response to my last comment? If using information obtained from the tools you must mention it explicitly without mentioning the tool names - I have forgotten all TOOL RESPONSES! Remember to respond with a markdown code snippet of a json blob with a single action, and NOTHING else - even if you just want to respond to the user. Do NOT respond with anything except a JSON snippet no matter what!")]

Help me solve the problem, thank you very much!